# display value for each XML element and to append them in a list.

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that I would like to read using Python ElementTree.

```
<items>
   <item>
      <title>title 1</title>
   </item>
   <item>
      <title>title 2</title>
   </item>
   <item>
      <title>title 3</title>
   </item>
</items>
```

I want to display value for each title element and to append them in a list. What I want to do is:

```
['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3']
```

Here is my source code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('asdad.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root.findall('item'):
    content = item.find('content').text
    title = [i for i in item.find('title').text]
    print(title)
```

But my source did not give the desired output.

Thank you to all !

Answer (score 0):

Get title like this. Not sure how you came up with `content`

```
title = item.find('title').text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comp finding all the titles with `findall('.//item/title')` and extracting the text from each:

```
 [t.text for t in root.findall('.//item/title')]
```